# looking for exact match with 2 excel sheets and return the data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In excel sheets there are two sub-sheets A and B contains name and id were named to compare with sheetB if it exact match retrieve the data and filled up with sheet.[image: sample picture]

ran up with vlookup and I cant help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the issue using `VLOOKUP`?

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SheetB!A:B,2,FALSE)
```